# Change pivot table source data to newest data File

Tags: excel, connection-string, pivot-table, excel-external-data, vba

I would like to have my pivot table in excel automatically update upon opening or in the background to the newest edition of data stored as a csv in a folder.

The csv files have the same columns and follow the same naming convention csvFile_ddmmyy where the date is substituted. They're run everyday.  I would like the excel to update the pivot tables source data to the newest dates data.

Preferably this will be done automatically, but i can also type in the date in a certain cell and have some macro to take this date and put it in the connection string.

If you may propose any solution to this problem, I'd greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0):

Make a copy of the latest CSV and use the same file name every time. Point the data connection to that one file that never changes its file name.

Comment: The files are quite large so I'd like to avoid his solution if possible. Are the solutions that I mentioned difficult to implement?

Comment: If you have a new CSV file every day, then what difference does one more file make? It's the same number of files that you would have tomorrow. It is far easier to copy a file with VBA than to manipulate a data connection with VBA. Just my 2 cents.